# javascript - Dynamically create nested json objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to be able to create and object like this

```
{'someKey':
    [{'someSubKey1': 'value1'},
    {'someSubKey2': 'value2'},
    {'someSubKey3': 'value3'}]
}
```

I tried a lot but I think I'm missing something

first of all I created an array and pushed the elements, then I did a JSON parse and finally a join (","), but the result wasn't the expected.

Some help?

Comment: The format is a little different: {'someKey':
    {'someSubKey1': 'value1',
    'someSubKey2': 'value2',
    'someSubKey3': 'value3'}
}

Comment: That is not a valid object. Do you want to create an array of objects each with a single property? Or should `someSubKey1`, `someSubKey2`, etc all be part of the same object? I recommend to read a tutorial about data structure in JS: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . Also, what has JSON to do with it?

Comment: `I tried a lot`. Could you please put the codes you tried?

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I miss the [ ] in the original post, I edited it now

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the contents in an array with `[]`. Wrap you inner json inside an array like

```js
var obj = {'someKey': [
    {'someSubKey1': 'value1'},
    {'someSubKey2': 'value2'},
    {'someSubKey3': 'value3'}]
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I miss the [ ] in the original post, I edited it now

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access your data structure like `myvar.someKey.someSubKey1`, consider this structure:

```
{   'someKey': 
    {
        'someSubKey1': 'value1',
        'someSubKey2': 'value2',
        'someSubKey3': 'value3'
    }
}
```

If you'd like to go with `myvar.someKey[0].someSubKey1`, try this:

```
{'someKey': 
    [
        {'someSubKey1': 'value1'},
        {'someSubKey2': 'value2'},
        {'someSubKey3': 'value3'}
    ]
}
```